# Div not expanding when on hover criteria met

Tags: html, jquery

For a page I am working on, there is hidden content within a div called projectTitle which shows once that div is hovered over, the div will expand to show it. This div is nested within another div called project and what I am trying to do is have this expand with it as well but I can't figure out why it won't. As well as this, I also have an arrow which I want to stay in the same position when projectTitle is hovered but it moves down as well. So my question would be, how can I get the project div to expand but also keep the arrow in its original place?

Here is a jsfiddle of my code to better explain what I am talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/dmpjL2e9/

I am using a mixture of jQuery and css to try do this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".projectTitle").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {
      $(this).find(".handoverExpanded").toggleClass('open');
      $(this).find(".project").toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

```css
.header img {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #555;
}

.header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 110px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#model {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.management {
  background-color: blue;
  /* Changing background color */
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Making font bold */
  border-radius: 70px;
  /* Making border radius */
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
  /* Making space around letters */
  font-size: 22px;
  /* Changing font size */
  color: white;
}

.management~.management {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

.project {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  /* Changing background color */
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Making font bold */
  border-radius: 70px;
  /* Making border radius */
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
  /* Making space around letters */
  font-size: 22px;
  /* Changing font size */
  height: 250px;
}

.projectTitle {
  position: inherit;
  background-color: green;
  right: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px!important;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.arrow1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 255px;
  display: block;
}

.handoverExpanded {
  position: inherit;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 220px;
  left: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.projectTitle:hover>.handoverExpanded {
  display: block;
}

.projectTitle:hover>.project {
  height: 400px;
}

.handoverExpanded {
  height: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  transition: height, 0.5s linear;
}

.handoverExpanded.open {
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  transition: height, 0.5s linear;
}

.project.open {
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
  transition: height, 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=h eader>
  <img id="logo" src="images/logo.jpg">

  <h1 class="title"> BUSINESS MODEL</h1>
</div>

<div id="model">
  <div class="management">
    Management Strategy, Goals and Objectives
  </div>
  <div class="management">HSSEQ</div>
  <div class="project">
    <p style="text-decoration: underline">Project Delivery Model</p>
    <div class="projectTitle">
      <p>Project Handover</p>
      <div class="handoverExpanded">
        <p>HSSEQ</p>
      </div>
      <div class="handoverExpanded">
        <p>Project Management</p>
      </div>
      <span class="arrow1">&#8594;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would first update to jQuery 3.6.0

Comment: I upgraded it but the animation I had no longer works, do you know why that would be?

Comment: remove your .arrow1 css `bottom:30px;` and set `top:0;`
check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vgedr9oq/

Comment: Thank you @groovy_guy! I don't suppose you know what's stopping the project div from expanding in height?

Comment: I assume a different working of [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: @lross15 to increase the height of your div you have to again make changes in css.. replace your div (.project) css `height: 250px;` to `min-height: 250px;`

Comment: Thought it would be a similar change but wasn't sure, thanks again @groovy_guy, it's much appreciated

Comment: I'll look into that @mplungjan, thanks